# Showing that a particular function defined from a smooth function is smooth.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k$ be a smooth map with $f(0)=0$. Define $F:[0,1]\times \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^k$ by:

$\left\lbrace \begin{array}{ccc} F(t,x)& =f(tx)/t & \text{if }t\neq 0 \\ F(0,x)&=df|_0(x). \end{array}\right.$

Show that $F$ is smooth.

I can show that some of the partials exist, but I am having a lot of trouble showing the partials with respect to $t$. I was wondering also if there is a slick way to solve this; showing that partials exist to all orders seems really gross.

Answer (score 1):

Each component is smooth. The second one is just a first derivative of $f$ at the origin. Well, f is smooth so that differential is smooth. To see the first component is smooth, observe that is is the composition and multiplication of smooth functions (since $t \not = 0$) i.e smooth.